# Combinatorial argument for identity with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof, combinatorial-proofs

My goal is to show :

$$\sum_{i=0}^{m} {n \choose i} {n - i \choose m - i} = {n \choose m} 2^m $$
where $$0 \leq m \leq n$$
I have algebraically proved that but I was wondering if there is a combinatorial argument for this proof.
Thank you

Comment: Your equation makes no sense: $i$ is a dummy variable with no fixed value on the lefthand side and a fixed constant of some kind on the righthand side.

Comment: That $i$ on RHS should probably be $m$.

Comment: I am sorry there was a typo. I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to count the number of subsets $A,B\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $A\subset B$ and $|B|=m$:

On the left you pick any subset $A$ of at most $m$ elements, and then extend it to a subset $B$ of $m$ elements. On the right you pick a subset $B$ of $m$ elements, and then pick any subset $A$ of $B$.

Comment: Very neat!${}{}$