# Cardinality Relations in Set Theory: Pairs and Binomial Identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $A$ be a non-empty set with $n$ elements.

a) Determine the number of pairs $(X, Y)$ where $X$ is included in $Y$, both included in $A$, and $\text{card}(X) = k$, $\text{card}(Y) = m$; $1 \leq k \leq m \leq n$, with $k$ and $m$ fixed.

b) Show that $\binom{0}{n}\binom{m}{n} + \binom{1}{n}\binom{m-1}{n-1} + \ldots + \binom{m}{n}\binom{0}{n-m} = 2^m \binom{m}{n}$.

My approach:
For a, I got $\binom{m}{n}\binom{k}{m}$ using the product rule but I might be wrong. For b) I considered $(X,\,Y)$ with $X\subseteq Y\subseteq A$ where $|X|=k,\,|Y|=m$. The number of such tuples is $\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{n} \binom{k}{m} = \binom{m}{n} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{k}{m} \right)$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: All your $\binom ab$ should be $\binom ba$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: @AnneBauval can you please edit it?

Comment: No, *you* should.

Comment: This is a duplicate (among [many](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5Em%5Cbinom%20nk%5Cbinom%7Bn-k%7D%7Bm-k%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Acombinatorial&p=1)) of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3851412